# Add a mobile number to LDAP mobile field

Tags: ldap

I'm new to LDAP and I've been looking how to do something for awhile now but with no results. I'd like to add a phone number to the mobile field through terminal command with this LDIF template dn:

```
uid=pnom,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
changetype: modify
delete: pouette
```

and how would I look for a certain name to check it worked? Thank you.

Comment: I do hope you don't expect that `changetype: modify \n` **`delete:`**  
will ever successfully **add**  anything to your LDAP directory...  Typically you check for success or failure by checking the return status of  your [`ldapmodify`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19693-01/819-0995/6n3cq3apv/index.html#bcacx) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to use *ldapmodify* command-line tool for sending a modify operation to your LDAP server. This tool takes LDIF as input. See [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) for LDIF specification, especially take a look at the examples.

An example LDIF snippet for adding a mobile number to an existing entry if the given value is not present in attribute *mobile*:

```
uid=pnom,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
changetype: modify
add: mobile
mobile: +1 2345 6789
-
```

The following replaces the complete attribute and its values with the two given values:

```
uid=pnom,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
changetype: modify
replace: mobile
mobile: +1 2345 6789
mobile: +4 567 89012345
-
```

The following would remove exactly one particular value from the attribute (delete-by-value):

```
uid=pnom,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
changetype: modify
delete: mobile
mobile: +4 567 89012345
-
```